Two finger touch to emulate right click on Ubuntu 24.04
Somehow I can't find the option in Gnome Tweaks anymore on a fresh Ubuntu 24.04 installation.
Before there was the Option Keyboard & Mouse > Mouse Click Emulation > Fingers
Any ideas how to get this back?

try using touchegg
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:touchegg/stable
sudo apt update
sudo apt install touchegg

with this gnome tweak, then follow upstream to configure it
for a gui install touché

Awesome, after installing both the twi-finger "right-click touch" just works <3
